# Minors obtaining Visa when parent lives in another country

Tags: standard-visitor-visas

Can a minor be accompanied to the UK office in Chicago by an adult other than their parent to obtain a standard visitor visa with the parent's permission? The Mother lives in Togo and the son is at a Boarding School in Illinois.

Comment: Read this https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/91843/what-do-i-need-to-legally-and-unproblematically-take-someone-elses-child-on-a-t/91844#91844, it's applicable. Answer is yes IF you are a legal guardian.

Comment: I don't get it, Chicago was hubbed about 10 years ago. Is the child using the super-premium service?

Answer (score 1):

First a note of clarification: the [UK Consulate in Chicago](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/usa-apply-for-a-uk-visa/apply-for-a-uk-visa-in-the-usa), a Premium Application Centre, does not accept Standard or Priority Visa applicants.

Such applications are [begun online](https://www.gov.uk/apply-uk-visa), fees paid, and biometrics done at at US Department of Homeland Security application support center. Only then is the application sent to the [British Consulate General in New York](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/usa-apply-for-a-uk-visa/apply-for-a-uk-visa-in-the-usa) for processing.

Minor children do not need to be accompanied interviews, but must provide the consent to travel of their parent(s) and, as appropriate, their legal guardian(s). As a minor and a third-country national applying in the United States for a UK visit visa, consent of both the parent(s) and the legal guardian(s) should be provided. The ECO has a statutory duty to protect children and would expect such documentation.

**[Gov.UK Standard Visitor Visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/if-youre-under-18) if you're under 18:**

> You can apply for a standard visitor visa if you’re under 18 and:
>
> - you’ve made suitable arrangements for your travel and stay in the UK
> - you have consent from your parent or guardian to travel to the UK
> - you’re able to pay for your return or onward journey
> - you have enough money to support yourself without working or getting help from public funds, or you have family and friends that can support you
>
> **Travelling alone**
>
> You can travel to the UK without an adult (someone over the age of 18).
>
> Your parent or guardian will need to provide their:
>
> - written consent for you to travel to the UK
> - full contact details
>
> They’ll also need to provide proof that you have somewhere suitable to live during your stay in the UK, including:
>
> - the name and date of birth of the person that you will be staying with
> - an address where you will be living
> - details of your relationship to the person who’ll be looking after you
> - consent in writing so they can look after you during your stay in the UK
>
> **Travelling with an adult**
>
> When travelling to the UK with an adult (someone over the age of 18), you’ll need to identify them in your visa application.
>
> If the person you’re travelling with isn’t your parent, you’ll need to provide specific information about them in your application.
>
> Their name will appear on your visa, and you’ll be refused entry to the UK if you arrive in the UK without them.
>
> You can identify up to 2 adults in your visa application, and your visa will only be valid if you travel with at least one of them.
>
> The adult can apply for a visa at the same time, but you must each complete separate applications.